# Helvetica Neue Ultralight font

Tags: css, fonts, font-face

I am searching for Helvetica Neue Ultralight font, because I want to embed it in my website with @font-face CSS. I also want to be able to make it a little bit bolder than default weight 100. Where can I find it?

Answer (score 0):

It's available here:

http://www.myfonts.com/fonts/linotype/neue-helvetica/webfont_preview.html

and here:

http://www.fonts.com/search/all-fonts?searchtext=Neue+Helvetica+25+Ultra+Light

Comment: But they're not free.

Answer (score 0):

http://www.myfonts.com/fonts/linotype/neue-helvetica/ there is a few different weights there. not exactly what you were looking for but close.